# How to join 3 tables or more

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables :

```
--------------------------------------------
DISPO,       ARTICLE,         SALES
--------------------------------------------
GQ_ARTICLE,  GA_ARTICLE,      GL_CODEARTICLE
GQ_PHISIQUE, GA_CODEARTICLE,  GL_QTEFACT
--------------------------------------------
```

DISPO & ARTICLE linked by :

```
DISPO.GQ_ARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_ARTICLE
```

ARTICLE & SALES linked by :

```
ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE = SALES.GL_CODEARTICLE
```

I Want to display :

```
ARTICLE.GA_ARTICLE, SUM(GQ_PHISIQUE), SUM(SALES.GL_QTEFACT)
```

I have tried this, the query executed but no result (more then 10 min with no result)

```
SELECT ARTICLE.GA_ARTICLE, SUM(GQ_PHYSIQUE), SUM(SALES.GL_QTEFACT)

FROM DISPO
INNER JOIN ARTICLE ON DISPO.GQ_ARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_ARTICLE
INNER JOIN SALES ON ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE = SALES.GL_CODEARTICLE

GROUP BY ARTICLE.GA_ARTICLE
```

Comment: No WHERE condition?

Comment: No result (not even 1 row) means that the problem is in the content of your tables and the joining conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your query does not work is that a straight join of the 3 tables returns duplicate rows which multiply the sum.
Join the 1st table with each of the other 2 separately and then join the results to the 1st table:

```
select 
  a.article
  d.totalphysique
  s.totalqtefact
from article a 
left join (
  select 
    a.ga_article,
    sum(d.gq_physique) totalphysique
  from article a inner join dispo d
  on d.gq_article = a.ga_article
  group by a.ga_article
) d on d.ga_article = a.ga_article
left join (
  select 
    a.ga_article,
    sum(s.gl_qtefact) totalqtefact
  from article a inner join sales s
  on s.gl_codearticle = a.ga_article
  group by a.ga_article 
) s on s.ga_article = a.ga_article
```

Comment: @hamza.soufiane I posted my answer before you edited and mentioned: *but no result (more then 10 min with no result)*. So if the problem is this, try your query with `select *` without group by and see if you have any results.

Comment: How large are your tables?

Comment: DISPO have all products (More then 200), Sales have the sales for each one of the products. Article have the description of all this products : like libelle, ..

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Try to make 1 join of article to 1 table. If it works make a join to dispo. If none works then there is a problem with your system or the tool you are using.

Comment: If ARTICLE has 1 row for each product and DISPO has 1 row for each product, why do you sum over GQ_PHYSIQUE?